# What do you call these different quotes?

Tags: string, symbols, quote

I got question about quote. There many few quote using documentation:

- `'`
- `
- `‘`
- `’`
- "
- `“`
- `”`

How to say or tell it in word?.

There few symbol quote not include in keyboard, (`“`, `‘`, `’`, `”`), how could I using symbol without copy-paste from other document.

As programmer view, it really matter write quote to make different from one to another?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it **definitely** matters!

- `'` single quote (aka apostrophe)
- `` ` `` backtick (aka grave)
- `"` double quote

The other ones (`‘`, `’`, `“`, and `”`) are simply known as "smart" or "curved" variants of their "straight" or "dumb" brethren (`'` and `"`).

Precisely *how* it matters depends on the programming language you're using.

[More info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs).

Answer (score 0):

depending on the language the quotes matter. A simple example can be done in bash, where quotes are everything:

```
bash$: "I am `whoami`"
I am root
bash$: 'I am `whoami`'
I am `whoami`
```

In the case of bash ( and many other languages ), using single quotes, vs double quotes has serious implications. Check the language you're using for documentation on how each token is treated.